# Unity 5.3.2 Pro, no Shadows

Tags: unity-game-engine, shadow

I'm rather new to Unity but some work landed on my desktop ..

I have a simple scene with a model of a dude (that comes from MakeHuman > Blendeer > *.mhx2 > Unity) a table (from Asset store) and a directional light.

Here you have them:

The dude:[image]

The table:

[image]

The light
[image]

And the game:

[image]

As you can see the dude cast no shadows :(  I'm aware that the scene was initaily created on Unity4.x and upgraded, but it never had shadows so I guess is not version-related.

I tried to add a meshRenderer to the dude, nothing changed :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `shadow type` you said no shadows change it to `hard` or `soft` shadows
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the inspector(light) have you tried to change the shadow type?

I can see it as "No shadows" and as i remember from my game if you enable it there, you enable shadows for all objects in the game

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how can I cast "not-so-dark" shadows? The scene look nicelly lit, but the shadows are WAY to dark. Any clue ?

Comment: Well if Soft Shadows dont help, try to turn the light of the sun (if you have any)

Comment: I added another (point) light at opposed side and the overall thing looks NICE. Thanks once more !